# mysql: how do i get a list of databases available?

Tags: sql, mysql, wampserver

i am using wampserver

i opened the mysql prompt

i would like to know which databases i am able to connect to/view. how do i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you opened the mysql prompt, write

```
show databases;
```

also, given the fact you have wamp, you can use phpmyadmin...

Answer (score 3):

`show databases;`

Answer (score 2):

show databases;